# Retrieve comments for specific thread

Tags: yammer

i just start using yammer rest api and i need to get the comment on some thread. 
The problem is, that, when i use the "**Threaded: extended**" parameter, i just got the 2 last comments. I tried to make a request using [message api](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/messagesjson) with "**older_than**" and "**newer_than**" parameter and as value, the "**first_reply_id**" and the "**latest_reply_id**" but it gave me another set of thread different from the comment list that i want to get.

Did anyone have an idea. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

finally and thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003722/yammer-rest-api-message-comments-and-message-history) i used the following rest URL :
messages/in_thread/[message_ID].json

Answer (score 0):

so, as i understand, the trick is to make request until the meta parameter "**older_available**" on json response is **false** or **null**, and for each message on the same json, check if the "**replied_to_id**" correspond to your thread ID. it's the only solution that i found until now and i'm not going to use it, as the rest api have limits on request number per time laps.